# Vert.x SharedData - can it reliably store an LRU?

Tags: cluster-computing, vert.x, lru, shared-data

I'm trying to store a list of things in the Vert.x cluster shared data, where the list if kind of like a queue, but things drop off of the queue based on a limit of number of elements - basically the same thing as a `LinkedHashMap` with a `removeEldestEntry()` implementation.

I've noticed that the main data storage facility in Vert.x `SharedData` is `AsyncMap` - where I can store a list in one of the values, but as far as I understand, if I have concurrent writers - then there will be data loss: unless I lock the map before and during each update - because if the storage mechanism is a list in a map entry, I will need to mutate the map value.

Is there another mechanism to store a mutable list in Vert.x `SharedData` that needs less locking?

I rather not get into needing a "real database" situation, because the system currently has none and I hoped to continue avoiding that for a little while longer.

Comment: what makes you think that there would be data loss by "concurrent writes"?

Comment: With a map that contains `somekey` mapped to an empty list, If one node does `sd.getAsyncMap(addr).compose(m -> m.get(somekey).onSuccess(l -> l.add(newval)).compose(l -> map.put(somekey, l)));`, and another node does the same thing at the same time, the list will have only one element, because both nodes saw an empty list and wrote a list with one value - there's no logic, AFAIK, that merges these lists.

Comment: well, if you write the same key into any map twice or more times, you will get a map size increased by 1

Comment: @injecteer , I see that, but the issue is which changes are reflected in the data stored in the async map? AFAIK `AsyncMap` guarantees atomicity only in regards to the `AsyncMap` operations (nominally, `put` and `get`) anything else - in my case, concurrently mutating a stored value, in a foreseeable manner - cannot be guaranteed and requires additional locking. [I deleted previous comments, as they do show lack of understanding]

Comment: if you need to mutate the value for the same key from different verticles over and over again, you run into the same problem any data source would have in this case. I don't see how `AsyncMap` would behave differently other than by "last write wins" policy

Comment: Yes, well - that was my original point: I don't want to use an `AsyncMap` because it has these problems. Is there something else that I can use? I edited my question to make it clear that I'm not complaining about `AsyncMap` not being able to do the things its not supposed to do.

Comment: you can create a verticle containing a `Map` with all your data. Although, I don't really see, how should it's usage be different from AsyncMap or any other data source

Comment: When you say "verticle containing a map", do you mean to use a verticle as a storage API and send event bus message to it to store and get data? (A) that would be useful in that it can be *not a map* but the actual LRU that I need (hence - better than a map); (B) but also it will be a single point of failure that I'm trying to avoid by using the `SharedData` API.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments discussion, it appears that the only way to safely and consistently store and retrieve data to the Vert.x `SharedData` `AsyncMap` API is to lock around any access that is more complex then "single put" or "single get". So my current implementation looks like this:

```java
/* This example stores strings for simplicity */
public Future<Void> addValue(String value) {
  return sharedData.getLock(SHARED_LOCK)
    .compose(lock -> sharedData.<String, List<String>>getAsyncMap(SHARED_DATA)
      .compose(map -> map.get(SHARED_KEY)
        .onSuccess(l -> l.add(value))
        .onSuccess(l -> {
          while (l.size() > MAX_SIZE)
            l.remove(0);
        })
        .compose(l -> map.put(SHARED_KEY, l))
      )
      .onComplete(__ -> lock.release())
    );
}
```

I would love to hear a better suggestion, because using a map to store a single list seems to me like a bad design.

Also, I didn't cover initializing the list at the first place - it should be trivial but complicates an already too complicated example, so I skipped that.